# R Plotly Contour Plots with Pattern Fill

Tags: r, plotly

I'm fairly new to using `plotly` package in R. I'm currently trying to create a contour plot using `plotly` package in R. For the colors of the contour plot, I would like to add a pattern fill like the bar chart created with the code below:

```
plot_ly(x = LETTERS[1:3],
        y = 6:4,
        color = letters[8:10],
        marker = list(pattern = list(shape = "x")),
        type = "bar")
```

However, the `marker = list(pattern = list(shape="x"))` does not work for the `type = "contour"`

Is there a way to fill with patterns and colors?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you need to change `marker = list(pattern...)` to `marker = list(color...)`. Then you can specify any color that, at least, comes with `colors()` if you type that into your console.

```
library(plotly)
plot_ly(x = LETTERS[1:3],
        y = 6:4,
        color = letters[8:10],
        marker = list(color = c("darkgrey","yellow","turquoise3")),
        type = "bar")
```

Or, more pertaining to your original example:

```
plot_ly(x = LETTERS[1:3],
        y = 6:4,
        color = letters[8:10],
        marker = list(color = list(shape = "x")),
        type = "bar")
```